# Adding string to link with jQuery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my  area I have a hidden input field with an ID. I would like to add this ID to the first link of my sidebar navigation.

My navigation:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.example.com">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

My desired modified output for the first link in this navigation:

```
<li><a href="http://www.example.com?id=25">Link 1</a></li>
```

For achieving this I have been trying out the following code:

```
<input id="input_id" type="hidden" value="' . <?php $id ?> . '">
<script>
    var id = '?id=' + jQuery("#input_id").val();
    var _href = jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").attr("href");
    jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").first().attr("href", _href + id);
</script>
```

It somehow doesn't work. The ID is not getting added as a GET parameter. Who can see the problem in here?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Pj96g/  In what way does yours not work?  When you debug this, what happens?  Do your selectors find the elements you expect?  Are the values what you expect?

Comment: Why do you have single quotes and periods inside of your double quotes? What do you mean by "It somehow doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always put jQuery code that manipulates the DOM inside a ready function

```
<script>
$(function(){
// put your code here.
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// put your code here.
});
</script>
```

Comment: There's no indication that this is the problem.  The code in question clearly comes after one of the elements it targets, it may also come after the other elements.  (At least in the order presented by the question, it already does.)

Comment: The only thing that is clear to me is that his JS comes immediately after this hidden input.  If the sidebar div is elsewhere in the page, this would be the reason he's having a problem.  He used a different code block in his question so I didn't assume that his code was in the same order.

Comment: @David this is the answer for the question. i was just about to post it. Those dom elements might not even have been created when the script executes.. http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Pj96g/1/

Comment: @TilwinJoy: jsFiddle automatically runs the code after the document is ready, that link doesn't really demonstrate anything.  Observe: http://jsfiddle.net/Pj96g/

Comment: @David right, i think i inspected the second or third link previously, but still this must be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems that I just fixed. Here is the working code:

```
<input id="input_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
<script>
var id = '?id=' + jQuery("#input_id").val();
var _href = jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").attr("href");
jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").first().attr("href", _href + id);
</script>
```

Comment: in the first line I originally had . <?php $id ?> .

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var _href = jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").attr("href");
```

is setting _href to an array. As it is, you're getting all of the href attributes from the a tags so when you use the next line

```
jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").first().attr("href", _href + id);
```

You're trying to append a string to an array of strings.

Try either getting the first href like this:

```
var _href = jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").first().attr("href");
```

Or you can add the id to each array item like this:

```
jQuery(".sidebar > ul > li > a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("href", _href + id);
});
```